# How to make Hudson build fail on checkstyle warning

Tags: hudson, checkstyle

I'm using Hudson continuous integration tool. I also run the checkstyle plugin as part of the build, and publish the checkstyle analysis result in Hudson. How could I make the build fail if I encounter a checkstyle error/warning?

I tried to add a rule to the Parsing Rules File, but this doesn't seem to work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It could be solved with Checkstyle plugin for Hudson/Jenkins. You can read about it [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Checkstyle+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

[gradle-estilo-plugin](https://github.com/anshulverma/gradle-estilo-plugin) provides the ability to fail the build if checkstyle task encountered errors. It also lets you specify rules in your build.gradle file instead of having separate files like checkstyle.xml, suppressions.xml, impor-control.xml etc.

You can instruct the `estilo` plugin to fail the build as:

```
estilo {
  ignoreWarnings false
}
```

On a side note, I must point out that I wrote this plugin myself and I use it extensively in all of my projects.